# PHP - replacing dot into arrows

Tags: php, laravel

I have this data in my database that i fetched:

As you can see i store an html template in my database.

This is the code i used to output that html:

```
$php = Blade::compileString($template->content);
dd($php) //i used laravel framework, btw.
```

Then this is the output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Exmaple.com</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="account-details">
        <b>Account Name</b>: <?php echo e(company.name); ?><br>
        <b>Plan</b>: <?php echo e(plan.name); ?><br>
        <b>Source</b>: <?php echo e(source.name); ?><br>
        <b>Source Type</b>: <?php echo e(source.source_type.name); ?><br>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="welcome" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:small">
        Hi <?php echo e(user.first_name); ?>,<br>
        <br>
        There seems to be a problem blah blah blah<br>
        <br>
        Details of the problem are:<br>
        <?php echo e(sourceMessage); ?><br>
        <br>
        You can check and update the source here:<br>
        https://example.com<br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size:12.8px">
            Kind regards,<br>
            <br>
           Test Team<br>
            <br>
            Email: <a href="mailto:test@example.com" target="_blank">example.com</a><br>
            Website: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example.com</a><br>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to change the `.`(dot) into `->` so in this example, some of text will output like:

from `<?php echo e(company.name); ?>` to `<?php echo e(company->name); ?>`

from `<?php echo e(source.name); ?>` to `<?php echo e(source->name); ?>`

So i think if it's in a `<?php echo e(whatever);  ?>` that's the time we check and replace the `.` with `->` ?

I think this can be done by RegEx but I'm not expert on that.

The reason why i wanted to replace it is because i am getting a template from an email service then returns `.`, so i wanted to replace that with `->` because I know PHP reads `->` in accessing objects rather than `.`.

Comment: I'm curious. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - i've updated the question as to why i wanted to do this.

Comment: aha. So you're basically getting code from a webservice that you want to translate into PHP-code?

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure how Laravel works but wouldn't it be better to change the functionality of e(whatever) ? so when you do execute that function you check if there's a dot and then use that as an object.  Once again. I'm just curious. I'm very humble about this because I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld the problem is that PHP would interpret `company.name` as the concatenation of two constants: `company` and `name`, resulting (probably) in two warnings and the string `companyname`, which would then be hard to parse in `e` to determine that what was actually meant was `$company->name`

Comment: @Nick .- aha ok thanks! I just wanted this to make sense to my mind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` to look for pieces of code matching `<?php ... e(f)` and replace the `.`s in `f` with `->`:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('/(<\?php\s+.*?\be\()([^)]+\))/',
                              function ($m) {
                                  return "{$m[1]}$" . str_replace('.', '->', $m[2]);
                              },
                              $html);
```

Note we use a callback as it makes it easier to deal with replacing `a.b.c` with `a->b->c`. Also, to really look like PHP, you need to add a `$` at the beginning of the variable name, which this code does. If you don't want it, just change `{$m[1]}$` to `{$m[1]}`

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Ivq5r)

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower I hadn't noticed; perhaps because you didn't show any attempt to solve it yourself? Some people don't like that even when you say you're not an expert at something.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing that on a editor like VS code or sublime, you just need to replace the function e usage parts.

CTRL + H 
(In sublime or VS code) to open up replace dialog.
Make sure the Regex option is clicked.

This would do the trick;

Search `(e\(.+)\.(.+\))`

Replace `$1->$3`